# How can I open a jpg format with QGIS 2.8?

Tags: qgis, jpg, qgis-2.8

I'm having some difficulties opening the jpg format at QGIS 2.8. It opens, but nothing appears.

Comment: Hi Christina! Could you please add information about the file in your question? Is this aplain jpg-file or does it also have some spatial information attached to it?

Answer (score 3):

More information about your jpeg would be helpfull.

But you just want to import the file you can load it as raster layer. But it won't have any georeferencing. If the picture is loaded as raster layer right click on the layer and select Zoom to Layer

If you want to import the jpeg with georeferencing and there is already geodata you can use the Georeferencer tool.
You can find it at `Raster -> Georeferencer -> Georeferencer...`
Load your jpeg with the `Open raster button` which is the first icon.
Then you click on the image and a `Enter map coordinates` dialog will appear. Now you can reference and add points from the map to your image by clicking `From map canvas`. You need at least three points that are spread widely over the map to get a proper result.