# Georeferencing a map without much info

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have part of a topographic map with contour lines and height points, but I don't have any further info about it. I know it must be in Balkan Zone 7 CRS and nothing more.

How should I georeference it (in QGIS)?

Comment: Is it a file or a paper map?

Comment: It is jpg file.

Comment: There may be geo-referencing attached to it.  Have you tried the Georeferencer Tool?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139364/how-can-i-open-a-jpg-format-with-qgis-2-8

Comment: It has no latitude or longitude marks on it? Are there any marks on it that you could get the location of, like mountain tops or villages?

Comment: Also maybe you have a grid on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned above, the georeferencing tool is probably your best bet (under raster|georeferencer). Although it is, perhaps, more commonly used to warp images with unknown projection (or no projection at all, such as historical maps), it will work in your case.

I would try something like that:

1. Load a base map (if you do not have one, one of the web maps -- google or osm--, maybe from the OpenLayers plugin at Web|openLayers, you probably need to install is first with plugins|manage and install plugins).
2. If you know for sure the projection of your raster: enable "on the fly" reprojection and then set the projection of your map canvas (bottom right button) to this CRS -- this is not strictly required, it is likely to give better results but may lead to troubles with the web maps, so you may want to try both options.
3. Launch the georeferencer plugin, load your image. Select the coordinate systems your raster is using. You then want to define some reference points that you can easily locate in both the raster, and the base map. Click on the point in the raster (from the georeferencer plugin window), a pop-up windows appears asking for the coordinates -- click on "from map canvas", then click on the same point in the main map. You want good, unambiguous reference points such as a tributary meeting a main river, a bridge (intersection of a road and a river), a crossroad... Depending on the scale of the map, a city (if represented by a dot) will do, or a prominent bend in a river or a coastline. As you add more points, they will appear under the image in a "GCP [ground control points] table, together with an error. The error will be materialized by a red line in the main georeferencer window [I wish QGIS could, as ArcGIS does, bend the image on the fly as you click on more GCP, but that's besides the point]. Use this to track errors, and remove/move the offending points.
4. Alternately, or in addition, you can also click on grid coordinates on your raster and type in the real coordinate.
5. If you can locate your points exactly, and your raster is projected in a known CRS, 4 points should be enough to fully define the scaling and rotation of your raster. Make sure they are as far apart as possible (the four corners are ideal). Open the "transformation settings" window (the cogwheel icon), set the CRS once more, leave the other options untouched (the first one should stay "linear transform"), tick "create world file only". Click on "Ok": this will create a worldfile containing the georeferencing information. Next time you'll load the image (immediately, if you selected the option "load in QGIS when done"), it will be georeferenced.
6. If you do not manage a clean job, for any reason (unknown projection, too difficult to locate exact GCP, etc) you probably want to add more GCPs to minimize the "average" error. As stated above, use the "error" column to select/unselect the points with too big an error (you can sort by error). Have your points sprinkled over all of the raster. Then, when launching the transformation, you may want to try other "transformation" options (thin plate, spline, etc.) : this will create a new, deformed version of your image, obviously (hopefully?) matching the reference map. Now load the modified map. This is probably less desirable, but is the only solution e.g. for unprojected rasters (an historical map maybe?), which does not seem to be your case.